# Iterating over records in an ExtJS store and filtering on a specific field

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs

I am iterating over records in a store as they come in like so:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Message',
    storeId: 'Staging',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        add: function(store, records, index, eOpts){
            if (!Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Historical').isLoading()) {

                this.each(function(item, index, count) {
                    if(item.notificationType === 'INBOX'){
                        // populate inbox store
                        // increment the unread inbox count
                        console.log('inbox');
                    } else if (item.notificationType === 'NOTIFICATION') {
                        // populate notifications store
                        // increment the unread notification count
                    }
                });

                // no historical data should be held in memory for performance
                this.removeAll();

            }  
        }
    }   
});
```

The *item.notificationType* property returns undefined.

I have tried other properties but they also return undefined.

I need to perform different actions when different types are encountered and thought this would do it!

So the item is a record in the store which contains json in the structure as follows:

```
   {
      "source":"2",
      "target":"1416529",
      "sourceType":"USER",
      "redirectUrl":null,
      "message":"cow's go...",
      "id":606,
      "targetType":"TEAM",
      "messageType":"TIBRR_WALL_MESSAGE",
      "notificationType":"INBOX",
      "sentDate":1356599137173,
      "parameters":null,
      "targetId":"1416529",
      "sourceId":"2",
      "dispatched":true,
      "read":false,
      "readDate":null,
      "dispatchedDate":1356599137377
   }
```

Comment: Is there a `notificationType` in your `item`? Actually, what _is_ `item`?

Comment: As per the docs item is the record in the store

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted your model definition, so I'm assuming you have a field in your model with the name "notificationType".

In that case, you'll want to use the get method:

```
item.get('notificationType');
```